# ng-disabled messing with tabbing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am having this weird issue with ng-disabled maybe someone else could have a look? The over arching issue is that when the search box gets focus I can no longer focus most of the tabbable elements on the modal, even the 'X' that closes the modal. The search box is contained in the `helpSearchTermsDiv` div. Once it gets focus, I can only tab through the focusable elements in its parent div `helpPopupHeader`. I have a modal (jquery ui) that contains the following directive:

```
helpModule.directive("helpDialog", ['helpService', '$timeout', 'translationService', function (helpService, $timeout, translationService) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            hc: '=helpHc',
            staticsBaseUrl: '@'
        },
        template: ' <div id="help-dialog">' +
                '       <div id="helpPopup" style="height:100%" class="help-dialog-contents-container">' +
                '           <div id="helpPopupHeader" class="help-popup-header help-header">' +
                '               <div id="helpPanelIconsDiv" class="help-panel-icons-div">' +
                '                   <button type="button" class="help-icon-small-back help-icon-small" ng-click="hc.back()" ng-disabled="!hc.canBack()" title="' + translationService.getMessage('SHOW_PREVIOUS') + '"></button>' +
                '                   <button type="button" class="help-icon-small-next help-icon-small" ng-click="hc.next()" ng-disabled="!hc.canNext()" title="' + translationService.getMessage('SHOW_NEXT') + '"></button>' +
                '                   <a class="help-toc-link" ng-click="helpToc()">'+translationService.getMessage("CONTENTS")+'</a>' +
                '                   <a class="help-index-link" ng-click="ctrl.helpIndex()">'+translationService.getMessage("INDEX")+'</a>' +
                '               </div>' +
                '               <div id="helpSearchTermsDiv" class="help-search-terms-div">' +
                '                   <input id="helpSearchTerms" ng-model="helpSearchTerms" title="{{searchHint}}" name="helpSearchTerms" ui-keyup="{\'enter\':\'helpSearch($event)\'}" ng-class="fieldClasses()" type="text" maxlength="50"/>' +
                '                   <button type="button" id="helpsubmitSearch" ng-disabled="searchHint == helpSearchTerms" class="help-search-button" title="' + translationService.getMessage('SEARCH_SUBMIT') + '" ng-click="helpSearch($event)"></button>' +
                '               </div>' +
                '           </div>' +
                '           <div id="help-popup-content" class="help-popup-panels">' +
                ....
```

If I remove the ng-disabled from the `helpsubmitSearch` button, I can tab through all tabbable elements in the modal. Also, if I click on the modal (so the search box loses focus) I can tab through all the elements until I get back to the search box and can only tab through the `helpPopupHeader` div. Any idea why that would be or things I could try?

Comment: Using `templateUrl` would help clean up your directive and remove the `<html/>`

Comment: `templateUrl` allows you to store your template in an external file or in a `<script type="text/ng-template>` element.